# Network HDD Dock

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, network-shares, docking-station

I was looking for a network HDD dock and came across the following:

FreeAgent DockStar Network Adapter

I was wondering if anyone had any experiences with it or any other suggestions?

I don't want a NAS - I just want a dock so I can plug hard drives into it and have it accessible via IP address etc.

Comment: You do want NAS, as that is what NAS is.

Comment: Well yes, but not something with static hard drives like a drobo, qnap :)

Comment: @paradroid: Kvad ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a DockStar - it works well.  It's essentially a tiny computer that can be set up to run OpenWrt or Linux, so if you're so inclined you can set it up as a iTunes server, BitTorrent server, etc in addition to serving as a hard drive host.  I'm using the plain-vanilla, out of box software load, and while it works with PogoPlug as the other poster mentioned, it's not necessary to use the PogoPlug software - you can set things up so that each USB drive that you plug into it is accessible via a network share.   The device's Amazon review has a good walkthrough on how to do this.

I like the device quite a bit.  The box is tiny and uses very little power, and mine has been reliable. I recommend it.

Comment: So how is the drive exposed on the network? Say from a windows pc \\ipaddress\share ? Doe it support EXT4 and NTFS?

Comment: The drive is exposed as a standard file share.  The share name is \\fadsMMMMMM\sharename, where MMMMMM is the last 6 characters in the DockStar's MAC address (shown on the bottom of the unit) and the sharename is user-configurable.  NTFS is supported - not sure about EXT4, but it probably is if you rebuild with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The DockStar uses the [Pogoplug](http://pogoplug.com/) service, which is great for accessing your files anywhere on the Internet. And when you outgrow what it offers, it provides opportunities for future growth.